# Will the compiler-generated default constructor be public?

Tags: java, default-constructor, member-access, compiler-generated

When I write a class `Widget.java`

```
public class Widget {
    int data;
    String name;
}
```

will the compiler-generated constructor be **public** or **default**?

public would be like

```
public class Widget {
    int data;
    String name;
    public Widget() {}
}
```

whereas default similar to

```
public class Widget {
    int data;
    String name;
    Widget() {}
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on your **class visibility**.The compiler uses the class visibility and generates a no-arg default constructor with the **same visibility**

Answer (score 6):

As said in [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9)

If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default constructor that takes no parameters is automatically provided:

1. If the class is declared public, then the default constructor is
   implicitly given the access modifier public;
2. If the class is declared protected, then the default constructor is
   implicitly given the access modifier protected;
3. If the class is declared private, then the default constructor is
   implicitly given the access modifier private;
4. Otherwise, the default constructor has the default access implied by
   no access modifier

Answer (score 1):

As classes visibility is public, it will always be a public constructor.

Answer (score 1):

It will be `public` as the class visibility is public

```
public Widget() {}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be 
    public Widget()
    {}

Answer (score 1):

Depends on class visibility. For your class dafault constructor is going to be public.

> In a class type, if the class is declared public, then the default constructor is implicitly given the access modifier public (§6.6); if the class is declared protected, then the default constructor is implicitly given the access modifier protected (§6.6); if the class is declared private, then the default constructor is implicitly given the access modifier private (§6.6); otherwise, the default constructor has the default access implied by no access modifier.

From [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9).

Answer (score 0):

If your class is public then the default constructor would be public so in your case, Since the Widget class is public its default constructor supplied by the compiler would also be public.
[See this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9)